# dictionary of nested variable length lists to pandas DF

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{ I1 : [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3]],
  I2 : [['B',2],['D',4]],
  I3 : [['A',2],['E',5]]
}
```

ie I have an index (the keys), then a variable number of pairs. I would like to create a pandas dataframe with the same index as the dictionary, where columns are the first values of the list pairs, values are the second values of the list pairs and NaNs are filled in for missing values (ie row I2 will have NaN in the 'A' column). Is there a slick way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

a={ 'I1' : [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3]],
    'I2' : [['B',2],['D',4]],
    'I3' : [['A',2],['E',5]]
  }


# create a list of dictionary from each rows

'''
The map function is used to convert say 'I3'
to integer 3, which can then be used to sort on
This is done because sorting  merely by the index string will lead to
say 'I15' to appear before 'I4'(assuming a more general 
case of you having more than just 3 indexes)
'''
# the sorted function is used because the order of keys is not maintained in a dict

row_dict = [dict(a[idx]) for _,idx in sorted(zip(map(lambda x: int(x[1:]),a),a))]

df=pd.DataFrame(row_dict)


    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   3 NaN NaN
1 NaN   2 NaN   4 NaN
2   2 NaN NaN NaN   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I1,I2,I3 are strings, you can use this :

```
import pandas as pd

a={ 'I1' : [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3]],
  'I2' : [['B',2],['D',4]],
  'I3' : [['A',2],['E',5]]
}

df=pd.DataFrame([dict(val) for key,val in a.items()])
print df

    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   3 NaN NaN
1   2 NaN NaN NaN   5
2 NaN   2 NaN   4 NaN
```

Comment: compare with @teamProbable solution

Comment: @protopopov : the original request was that the index of the dataframe was the same as the dictionary. A dictionary is not ordered, so why I2 should be before I3 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use @manu190455 solution but sort it before passing to `pandas.DataFrame` with `sorted` and `key` argument:

```
d = { 'I1' : [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3]],
    'I2' : [['B',2],['D',4]],
    'I3' : [['A',2],['E',5]]}

sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[0])

In [263]: sorted_d
Out[263]:
[('I1', [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3]]),
 ('I2', [['B', 2], ['D', 4]]),
 ('I3', [['A', 2], ['E', 5]])]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(val) for key, val in sorted_d])

In [265]: df
Out[265]:
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   3 NaN NaN
1 NaN   2 NaN   4 NaN
2   2 NaN NaN NaN   5
```